# CSS Class Selector hover

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to make a navigation bar with small images which respond(by margin 10px from the top) when you hover over them. I applied the hover effects via a class Selector,
however when I hover over one image the rest of them respond as well. So, can I correct this with the class Selector?

Here's the html side.

```
<a href=""><img class="menu" src="weight.png" /></a>
<a href=""><img class="menu" src="height.png" /></a>
```

Here's the css:

```
.menu{
    height:100px;
    width:100px; 
    transition:all 0.3s ease-in; margin-left:15px; 
    margin-top:5px;
}
.menu:hover{
    margin-top:15px;
    transition:all 0.3 ease-in;
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default vertical alignment for inline content is "baseline". This means that your images by default stick to the bottom of your `a` elements. To fix this, you simply need to set the [vertical alignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) on your `img` elements to "top":

```css
.menu {
    ...
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5zGr5/).

Comment: I don't quite get why it works, but it works. Thank you very much!